# Retrieving Temporary Access Token using jQuery OAUTH

Tags: javascript, jquery, oauth-2.0, shopify

I am attempting to make an API OAUTH2 call to Shopify to authenticate. When I go to my application, the first screen comes up. I press Install, and then it redirects me back to where I started. The problem is that when I get redirected, I cannnot seem to catch it in my jQuery ajax function and therefore I am unable to get the temporary token I need to create my permanent token from OAUTH. The 2nd image shows what is happening after I press install. My code so far is posed below. None of the console.log() functions are being called after I run the ajax call.

My application URL for my app is set to

```
http://localhost
```

and my application is running from

```
http://localhost/shippingcalculator.
```

I tested the calls in an external REST client program, and I managed to successfully get my access token, so it is not a problem with my credentials.

[image: 200OK and then the 302 Redirect]

[image: Runs fine in a REST client tester]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
    var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
    var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
    console.log(window.location.search);
    var results = regex.exec(window.location.search);
    if (results == null) return "";
    else return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

function getTemporaryToken(token) {
    jso_configure({
        "shopify": {
            client_id: "67d7af798dd0a42e731af51ffa", //This is your API Key for your App
            //redirect_uri: "", OPTIONAL - The URL that the merchant will be sent to once authentication is complete. Must be the same host as the Return URL specified in the application settings
            authorization: "https://emard-ratke3131.myshopify.com/admin/oauth/authorize",
            //In your case the authorization would be https://SHOP_NAME.myshopify.com/admin/oauth/authorize
            scope: ["read_products"], //Set the scope to whatever you want to access from the API. Full list here: http://api.shopify.com/authentication.html
        }
    });
    $.oajax({
        url: "https://emard-ratke3131.myshopify.com/admin/oauth/authorize",
        jso_provider: "shopify",
        jso_scopes: ["read_products"],
        jso_allowia: true,
        success: function(data) {
            //Use data and exchange temporary token for permanent one
            if (jqXHR.status === 200) {
                console.log("200");
            }
            if (jqXHR.status === 302) {
                console.log("300");
            }
            console.log("Response (shopify):");
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(e) {
            console.log("Fail GET Request");
            console.log(e);
        },
        complete: function(xmlHttp) {
            // xmlHttp is a XMLHttpRquest object
            console.log(xmlHttp.status);
        }
    });
    console.log("Code: " + getParameterByName("code"));
}
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    getTemporaryToken();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
Hello World!
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a pretty bad idea to do all of this client side, your API key will be in the clear for anyone to see and use. On top of that where will you store the token? There are also cross site scripting restrictions built into all browsers that will prevent JavaScript from making calls to sites other than the one the js is loaded from.

You should really do the authentication and make all your API calls from a server.

Comment: Ok, I have written up a node.js server to aid with my OAUTH calls

Comment: storing the token in cookie or html5 local storage is not bad idea